# Laravel 7: Finding a relation between two dates

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship, laravel-relations

I'm trying to get the jobs relation between two dates by using the `whereHas` method however I keep getting an  `Integrity constraint violation` and am not sure what is causing this issue.

I've tried using the `with` and `where` method, but they all return the same error.

**Error:**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in where clause
is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `categories` where exists (select * from `jobs` inner
join `category_job` on `jobs`.`id` = `category_job`.`job_id` where `categories`.`id` = `category_job`.`category_id` and `created_at` = `=<` and `created_at` >= `2022-06-19 23:59:59`))
```

**Function:**

```
    /**
     *
     */
    public function categoriesThisWeek()
    {
        $categoriesThisWeek = Category::with('jobs')
            ->whereHas("jobs", function ($query) {
                $query
                    ->whereColumn('created_at', '=<', Carbon::now()->startOfWeek())
                    ->whereColumn('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->endOfWeek());
            });

        return  $categoriesThisWeek->get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both tables probably have a `created_at` column so you need to specify which one (`tbl1.created_at`) you want to use.

Comment: You could mark it as correct then.

Comment: Yes, there was a countdown on it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors, one is using `whereColumn` instead of `where` without precising the table and using values (whereColumn is to compare a column to another one) and the other is using the operator `=<` which doesn't exist.

```
public function categoriesThisWeek()
{
    $categoriesThisWeek = Category::with('jobs')
        ->whereHas("jobs", function ($query) {
            $query
                ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->startOfWeek())
                ->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->endOfWeek());
        });

    return  $categoriesThisWeek->get();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. adding `jobs.created_at` managed to fix the issue!

Comment: @Salman no, it will not fix your issue. check the results you're getting first.